# When is a data.frame in R numeric?

Tags: r, dataframe, character, numeric

I stumble on the following problem. I have a `data.frame`

```
A <- data.frame(let = c("A", "B", "C"), x = 1:3, y = 4:6)
```

The classes of its columns are

```
sapply(A, class)
      let         x         y 
 "factor" "integer" "integer" 
s.numeric(A$x)
[1] TRUE
is.numeric(A)
[1] FALSE
```

I do not understand why although `A$x` and `B$x` are numeric, the `data.frame` composed only by these two columns is not numeric

```
is.numeric(A[, c("x", "y")])
[1] FALSE
```

Removing the `factor` column does not help...

```
B <- A
B$let <- NULL
is.numeric(B)
[1] FALSE
is.numeric(B$x)
[1] TRUE
is.numeric(B$y)
[1] TRUE
```

So, I tried creating a new dataset built only with the numeric columns in `A`. Is it numeric? No...

```
C <- data.frame(B$x, B$y)
is.numeric(C)
[1] FALSE
C <- data.frame(as.numeric(B$x), as.numeric(B$y))
is.numeric(C)
[1] FALSE
```

There must be something I'm missing here. Any help?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I realized that the example is not really equal to the problem I had (which is solved now). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry akrun, I didn't mean it bad. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A data frame is always a data frame, independent of the classes of its columns. So what you get is the expected behaviour

If you want to check whether all columns in a data frame are numeric, you can use the following code

```
all(sapply(A, is.numeric))
## [1] FALSE
all(sapply(A[, c("x", "y")], is.numeric))
## [1] TRUE
```

A table with only numeric data can also be understood as a matrix. You can convert the numeric columns of your data frame to a matrix as follows:

```
M <- as.matrix(A[, c("x", "y")])
M
##      x y
## [1,] 1 4
## [2,] 2 5
## [3,] 3 6
```

The matrix `M` is now really numeric:

```
is.numeric(M)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

We need to apply the function on the `vector` and not on the `data.frame`

```
sapply(A[c("x", "y")], is.numeric)
```

instead of

```
is.numerc(A)
```

as according to `?is.numeric`

> Methods for is.numeric should only return true if the base type of the class is double or integer and values can reasonably be regarded as numeric (e.g., arithmetic on them makes sense, and comparison should be done via the base type).

The `class` of 'A' is `data.frame` and is not `numeric`

```
class(A)
#[1] "data.frame"

sapply(A, class)
```

`is.numeric` returns TRUE only if the `class` of the object is `numeric` or `integer`.

---

Thus, a `data.frame` can never be `numeric` unless we apply the `is.numeric` on the `vector` or the extracted column.  That is the reason, we do it on a loop with `lapply/sapply` where we get the column as a `vector` and its class would be the class of that column